# using group by for getting some statistic data from one table with bulk records and puting the results into the second table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, foreach, group-by

As I explained in title I have 2 tables :
1 - "Leaves" with 21000 rec of leaves for about 50 peoples during 20 years
2- "StatisticLeave" which is empty
now i want to use group by for getting some statistic data from table 1 and after doing some calculation (like sum & ...) putting the results into the second table.
I wrote below code :

```
public ActionResult UserStatistic()
    {
        
        var ST = new List<StatisticLeave>();
        var resuls = db.Leaves.GroupBy(p => p.Pcode);
        foreach (var Pcode in resuls)
        {
            var statistic = new StatisticLeave();
            foreach (var item in Pcode)
            { 
                var used = UsedLeaves(item.Pcode);
                var estelaji = db.Leaves.Where(p => p.DLT == Leave.DLType.Estelaji).Sum(p => p.LeaveDays);
                var bh = db.Leaves.Where(p => p.DLT == Leave.DLType.Bihoghoogh).Sum(p => p.LeaveDays);               
                statistic.Yearlyhours = ViewBag.mins/60;
                statistic.YearlyDays = ViewBag.days;
                statistic.YearEstelaji = estelaji;
                statistic.YearBihoghoogh = bh;
                statistic.Pcode = item.Pcode;
                statistic.Year = item.HijriYear;
                statistic.UsedYearLaeve = (used / 60) / 8;
                ST.Add(statistic);
            }
            db.StatisticLeave.AddRange(ST);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

when I trace the code i get the following caution:

"System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side."

would you please tell me where is the problem or how can i fix it.

Comment: Have you read the suggestion in the exception message itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code as below and the problem Solved

```
public ActionResult UserStatistic(Int32? PCode)
{
    var ST = new List<StatisticLeave>();
    var results = db.Leaves.Where(p => p.Pcode == PCode).ToLookup(p => p.HijriYear);
    foreach (var HijriYear in results)
    {
        var statistic = new StatisticLeave();
        
        foreach (var item in HijriYear)
        {
            var used = UsedLeaves(item.Pcode, item.HijriYear);
            var estelaji = db.Leaves.Where(x => x.Pcode == item.Pcode).Where(p => p.DLT == Leave.DLType.Estelaji).Where(p => p.HijriYear == item.HijriYear).Sum(p => p.LeaveDays);
            var bh = db.Leaves.Where(x => x.Pcode == item.Pcode).Where(p => p.DLT == Leave.DLType.Bihoghoogh).Where(p => p.HijriYear == item.HijriYear).Sum(p => p.LeaveDays);                  
            statistic.Yearlyhours = ViewBag.mins / 60;
            statistic.YearlyDays = ViewBag.days;
            statistic.YearEstelaji = estelaji;
            statistic.YearBihoghoogh = bh;
            statistic.Pcode = item.Pcode;
            statistic.Year = item.HijriYear;
            statistic.UsedYearLaeve = (used / 60) / 8;
            ST.Add(statistic);
        }
        db.StatisticLeave.AddRange(ST);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```